# Canceling a CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java, java-8

I have a chain of asynchronous service calls which I would like to cancel. Well, actually, I have **two** chains of service calls going in parallel, and if one succeeds, I would like to cancel the other.

With guava's futures I'm accustomed to canceling an entire chain of Futures by canceling the last one. It appears I cannot do this with java-8's futures. **Unless someone has a good idea of how.**

**You're task, should you choose to accept it**, is to tell me if I can keep my pretty syntax AND have the chain cancellation. Otherwise, I'll be writing my own chaining future wrapper - especially after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25338376/4931%20withFallback).

---

My own tests and attempts follow.

```
@Test
public void shouldCancelOtherFutures() {
    // guava
    ListenableFuture<String> as = Futures.immediateFuture("a");
    ListenableFuture<String> bs = Futures.transform(as, (AsyncFunction<String, String>) x -> SettableFuture.create());
    ListenableFuture<String> cs = Futures.transform(bs, (AsyncFunction<String, String>) x -> SettableFuture.create());
    ListenableFuture<String> ds = Futures.transform(cs, Functions.<String>identity());

    ds.cancel(false);
    assertTrue(cs.isDone()); // succeeds

    // jdk 8
    CompletableFuture<String> ac = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("a");
    CompletableFuture<String> bc = ac.thenCompose(x -> new CompletableFuture<>());
    CompletableFuture<String> cc = bc.thenCompose(x -> new CompletableFuture<>());
    CompletableFuture<String> dc = cc.thenApply(Function.identity());

    dc.cancel(false);
    assertTrue(cc.isDone()); // fails
}
```

(Imagine that each `thenCompose()` and `Futures.transform(x, AsyncFunction)` represents an asynchronous service call.)

I can see why Doug Lee's army of grad students did it this way. With branching chains, should everything be canceled?

```
CompletableFuture<Z> top = new CompletableFuture<>()
    .thenApply(x -> y(x))
    .thenCompose(y -> z(y));

CompletableFuture<?> aBranch = top.thenCompose(z -> aa(z));
CompletableFuture<?> bBranch = top.thenCompose(z -> bb(z));

...
bBranch.cancel(false);
// should aBranch be canceled now?
```

I can get around the problem with a custom wrapper function, but it messes up the pretty syntax.

```
private <T,U> CompletableFuture<U> transformAsync(CompletableFuture<T> source, Function<? super T,? extends CompletableFuture<U>> transform) {
    CompletableFuture<U> next = source.thenCompose(transform);
    next.whenComplete((x, err) -> next.cancel(false));
    return next;
}

private <T,U> CompletableFuture<U> transform(CompletableFuture<T> source, Function<T,U> transform) {
    CompletableFuture<U> next = source.thenApply(transform);
    next.whenComplete((x, err) -> next.cancel(false));
    return next;
}

// nice syntax I wished worked
CompletableFuture<?> f1 = serviceCall()
        .thenApply(w -> x(w))
        .thenCompose(x -> serviceCall())
        .thenCompose(y -> serviceCall())
        .thenApply(z -> $(z));

// what works, with less readable syntax
CompletableFuture<?> f2 =
        transform(
            transformAsync(
                transformAsync(
                    transform(serviceCall, x(w)),
                    x -> serviceCall()),
                y -> serviceCall()),
            z -> $(z));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what your goal is. I assume, that it is not important to have your intermediate `CompletableFuture`s report a completed state as you usually won’t notice when using chained construction call. The important point is that you wish your expensive `serviceCall()` not to be triggered.

One solution can be:

```
CompletableFuture<String> flag=new CompletableFuture<>();

CompletableFuture<String> ac = serviceCall()
  .thenCompose(x -> flag.isCancelled()? flag: serviceCall())
  .thenCompose(x -> flag.isCancelled()? flag: serviceCall());
ac.whenComplete((v,t)->flag.cancel(false));// don’t chain this call
```

This uses the `whenComplete` call like in your solution but only on the final `CompletableFuture` to propagate the cancellation to a dedicated `flag` object. After calling `cancel` the next `thenCompose` invocation will detect the cancellation and return the cancelled future, thus the cancellation will propagate the chain then so no more compose or apply methods are invoked.

The drawback is that this can not combined with `thenApply` as the `Function` can’t return a cancelled future. Therefore, when the asynchronous service call completes and is chained with a `Function`, the function will be applied even if a cancellation occurred.

The alternate solution solving this issue as well is to create a wrapper function for your `serviceCall` which includes a test before launching and after completion:

```
CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall(CompletableFuture<String> f) {
    if(f.isCancelled()) return f;
    CompletableFuture<String> serviceCall=serviceCall();
    return serviceCall.thenCompose(x->f.isCancelled()? f: serviceCall);
}
```

Then your use case will look like:

```
CompletableFuture<String> flag=new CompletableFuture<>();

CompletableFuture<String> ac = serviceCall(flag)
  .thenApply(w->x(w))
  .thenCompose(x -> serviceCall(flag))
  .thenCompose(x -> serviceCall(flag))
  .thenApply(z -> $(z));
ac.whenComplete((v,t)->flag.cancel(false));
```

Of course, you have to replace `<String>` with whatever type parameter your original `serviceCall()` uses for the `CompletableFuture<T>`.

Comment: A caveat with these approaches: ac.isCancelled() will not be true because somewhere the CancellationException is wrapped in a CompletionException

Comment: @Michael Deardeuff: it worked in my test setup and I never dealt with a `CancellationException` so I have no such issue. It could be when calling `get` but when chaining like in your question you will never invoke `get`.

Comment: Maybe the confusion arose because I didn’t explicitly state that you should use it like within your question: the constructed `ac` is the only `CompletableFuture` you should care about, it’s the one you use for retrieving completion state and result and the one you cancel when appropriate; the helper `flag` is only relevant during construction. So when you want to `cancel` you should invoke cancel on `ac` which will then immediately reflect that is has been cancelled, of course. (Unless it already completed before the `cancel` call.

Comment: Oh, it's not going to stop me from using it. The caveat was for people who come later and don't try it out in unit tests.